# Linux kernel yield() functionality

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, ubuntu-10.04, vmware-player

When I start VMWare Player it gives me this message:

[image]

How can I setup my system so that this yield() functionality is automatically enabled?

Answer (score 5):

Create a file called `/etc/sysctl.d/99-awakeFromNib-vmware.conf` containing the line

```
kernel.sched_compat_yield=1
```

This file is read at boot time. For this session, just click OK.

You can view or change the setting at any time by reading or writing the file `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_compat_yield`.

**ADDED**: Settings like these are called kernel parameters, or sysctl's for short. (They are not the same thing as kernel *command line* parameters that you can set in your bootloader, though you *can* set sysctl's on the kernel command line.) The principle is documented in `man sysctl`, and most settings are documented in `Documentation/sysctl/*.txt` in the Linux kernel documentation.

Comment: I don't get it. What's the difference between creating the vmware.conf file and editing the one in /proc/sys/kernel?

Comment: The settings in `/proc/sys` apply to the running kernel. They're lost when you reboot. The settings in `/etc/sysctl.d` are applied during the boot process.

Comment: In /proc/sys/kernel/sched_compat_yield there is only one thing written in it: 1. Does this mean that it's already turned on? Shouold this be replaced with kernel.sched_compat_yield=1?

Comment: @awakeFromNib: `/proc/sys/foo/bar` contains the value of the `foo.bar` setting. `kernel.sched_compat_yield` is a boolean setting, so it's on if `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_compat_yield` contains 1 and off if `/proc/sys/kernel/sched_compat_yield` contains 0. (In fact the file contains a final newline when you read it; if you write to the it manually you can omit that final newline.) So the answers to your questions are 1: yes; 2: no.

Answer (score 4):

Using Ubuntu 10.10, VMware Workstation creates the 30-vmware-player file in `/etc/sysctl.d` but Ubuntu is looking for files that end in `.conf` - it seems to ignore all others.

Rename the `30-vmware-player` file to `30-vmware-player.conf`

```
sudo mv /etc/sysctl.d/30-vmware-player /etc/sysctl.d/30-vmware-player.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote the line above: `kernel.sched_compat_yield=1` directly to `/etc/sysctl`, and the app (vmware-workstation) never showed the *message* again (screen shot at the top of this page).

If I just said yes to the message, the app would create the file `30-vmware-player` in `/etc/sysctl.d/` but I would still get the message after running vmware-workstation after rebooting (maybe because the name of the file -player, instead of -workstation).

Answer (score 2):

I have failed to set `kernel.sched_compat_yield=1` but have given up trying.

Using Ubuntu 9.10, `VMware Workstation 7.1.2 build-301548`

If I click OK then 
  my Windows 7 VM grabs my USB keyboard and mouse and hangs, requiring a hard reboot.

If I just cancel then 
  the mouse and keyboard work well inside and outside the VM.

Answer (score 2):

Tested on 11.04 (Natty Narwahl) - I edited `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf
```

and added this line at the bottom of the file:

```
kernel.sched_compat_yield=1
```

Save the file and exit then initialize the new settings with:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

You should never see the message again.